# Fixed buttons between scrollable content

Tags: android, scrollview

i'm struggling with scrollview.

I want to display content (1) then buttons (2) and finally content (3).

When i'm scrolling, i want the buttons to be fixed at the top of my activity.

I can't post image, so it would be :

```
1
2
3
```

I scroll

```
2 (fixed at top)
3 (this part start to scroll when the 1 disapear at top)
```

I scroll

```
2 (fixed at top)
3 (still scrollable).
```

I m curently using this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_entete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_bar"
    android:background="@color/gris_blanc" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_conteneur"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        // Some image etc.

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_presentation_has_to_stay_on_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sv_entete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_analyze_has_to_stay_on_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sv_entete" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_presentation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_presentation"
    android:background="@color/gris_blanc" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_presentation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         // Some image etc

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But only the second part scroll (3), the first part (1) is (obviously) not linked with the second scrollview, but i can't figured out by myself.

Any help plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no way to implement it right out of the box. So, You need to create custom components.
Unfortunately, there's not much details in the question, so I'm not able to suggest which way is better for your case.
However, below two variants I can think of:

- Have two button panels in the same layout. Initially only one panel should be visible (one inside scroll view). During scrolling, it first panel reaches top, You'll need to make second one visible. And make it invisible, when scroll up (and first one become visible inside `ScrollView`). It would increase complexity of layout and coe little bit (e.g. You'll need to listen two sets of buttons instead of one). In simple test application I haven't observed any critical issues / UI artifacts using this implementation,
  For that you need to create separate layout for buttons panel, e.g. **buttons_panel.xml**:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_presentation_has_to_stay_on_top"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="left button"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_analyze_has_to_stay_on_top"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="right button"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  Then main activity layout might look like the following (**activity_main.xml**):

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <com.alexstarc.testapp.ObservableScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/sv_entete">

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/layout_conteneur"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="300dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_1"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 1"/>

              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="250dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_1_1"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_1"
                  android:src="@drawable/img1"/>

              <include
                  layout="@layout/buttons_panel"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/middle_button_panel"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_1_1" />

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="100dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_2"
                  android:layout_below="@id/middle_button_panel"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 2"/>

              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="350dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_3"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_2"
                  android:src="@drawable/img3"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="250dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_4"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_3"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 4 (1)"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="100dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_5"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_4"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 5"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="350dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_6"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_5"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 6"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="250dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_7"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_6"
                  android:background="@drawable/img1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 7"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="250dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_8"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_7"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 8"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="100dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_9"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_8"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 9"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="350dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_10"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_9"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 10"/>

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="250dp"
                  android:id="@+id/image_11"
                  android:layout_below="@id/image_10"
                  android:background="@drawable/img1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:text="Image 11"/>
          </RelativeLayout>
      </com.alexstarc.testapp.ObservableScrollView>

      <include
          layout="@layout/buttons_panel"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/top_button_panel"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:visibility="gone" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

  There's special custom `ViewGroup` - `ObservableScrollView`. It's needed, because `ScrollView` doesn't have any listeners for observing scroll position, but we need to detect then buttons panel inside it become visible. Here's its draft code (please note, I haven't done any optimization or full testing):

  ```
  public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {

      private int mTrackViewId = 0;
      private View mTrackView = null;
      private int mTrackViewTop = 0;
      private int mTrackViewDown = 0;
      private OnViewReachTop mTopReachListener = null;

      /* Helper interface to notify listener about */
      public interface OnViewReachTop {
          /**
           * Called then View riches top
           */
          void onReachTop();

          /**
           * Called then view leaves top position
           */
          void onLeaveTop();
      }

      public ObservableScrollView(final Context context) {
          super(context);
      }

      public ObservableScrollView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
      }

      public ObservableScrollView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      }

      /**
       * Sets view id to be tracked and corresponding callback
       *
       * @param viewId id of view to be trackked
       * @param listener {@link com.alexstarc.testapp.ObservableScrollView.OnViewReachTop} to be called
       */
      public void setViewTopTracking(final int viewId, final OnViewReachTop listener) {

          mTrackView = findViewById(viewId);

          if (mTrackView == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passed view id should be from child of this scroll view");
          }

          mTrackViewId = viewId;
          mTopReachListener = listener;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt) {

          if (mTrackViewDown == 0 && mTrackViewTop == 0) {
              mTrackViewDown = mTrackView.getBottom();
              mTrackViewTop = mTrackView.getTop();
          }

          super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

          if (getScrollY() >= mTrackViewTop) {
              mTopReachListener.onReachTop();
          } else if (getScrollY() <= mTrackViewDown) {
              mTopReachListener.onLeaveTop();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  And activity code, which will observe current scroll position and show / hide second buttons panel:

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ObservableScrollView.OnViewReachTop {

      private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
      private View mButtonsPanel;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          mButtonsPanel = findViewById(R.id.top_button_panel);
          ((ObservableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sv_entete)).setViewTopTracking(R.id.middle_button_panel, this);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onReachTop() {
          mButtonsPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onLeaveTop() {
          mButtonsPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  }
  ```
- Second way: take `ScrollView` code, analyze it and make possible to fix some view on the top. This way is more complex, but possible to implement. Please, investigate it (if first one is not applicable to your code / layout) and ask additional questions if face some particular problems with it.